# ASP Error 0223 - TypeLib Not Found, intermittent, resolved after IIS restart

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-6, ado, iis-8.5

I'm currently in the process of migrating an ASP platform from Windows 2003 R2 IIS 6 web servers to Windows 2012 R2 IIS 8.5 web servers. I'm at the stage where I've migrated a number of sites across to two separate 2012 web servers, all looked great, clients and developers are happy... However the following error has presented itself after a few days hosting on one of the new servers.

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0223'

TypeLib Not Found

/jobboard/conf/constants.vbs.inc, line 1

METADATA tag contains a Type Library specification that does not match any Registry entry.
```

The METADATA tag is below:

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" UUID="{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}" VERSION="2.8"-->
```

Restarting IIS on this server resolved the issue (albeit temporarily).

Subsequently the other 2012 web server in production presented the same error a couple of days later, again, restarted IIS and works for now.

I've checked the registry and the relevant tag exists with the right UUID and correct permissions.

It doesn't affect all sites on the server, only all sites in a particular application pool.

The application pools use a domain user identity and sites are split up into a number of shared pools.

Comment: Is the app pool running in 32-bit mode? Only reason I can think for IIS to not find the registry entry was if it was looking in the wrong registry hive *(32 versus 64 bit)*

Comment: On 64 bit architecture servers 32 bit Classes are stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes` while 64 bit classes are stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`.

Comment: The fact it is intermittent though doesn't point to that.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your time! The app pools are running in 64-bit mode. The ASP application has also come from a 64-bit environment with 64-bit app pools.

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12779685/692942

Comment: My first guess was it could have been down to memory usage of the application pool.. Perhaps something somewhere was having trouble accessing memory above the 32-bit limit somewhere? But, as I say, IIS pools are 64-bit, and all 3rd party components are 64-bit also, as well as the OS.

Comment: Does the App Pool recycle often?

Comment: The application pools are configured to recycle every 1740 minutes, which is the IIS default I think. It's not been changed here. In terms of how frequently they actually are recycling... I'm still seeing the same PIDs I saw 8 hours ago right now. And we've not had support calls about complaints of sessions being lost. I will be keeping an eye on the PIDs to check they are recycling as they should.

Comment: Find a few references to very similar problems online but they are a few years old - http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=640096. Is the Windows Server 2012 web server fully patched? Can't say I've ever had this issue myself but I tend to run in 32 bit mode due to legacy COM+ components.

Comment: If the problem with accessing the `UUID` try using `FILE` instead and see if you have the same issues, I tend to use `FILE` in my `METADATA` statements instead of `UUID` because I have control of the servers.

Comment: Yeah there's some chatter about it online, and a couple of related posts on here, but largely unresolved :(. Servers are all patched up as far as last month's patch Tuesday.

Comment: You might find the permissions needed in the registry aren't what you expect for example the Application Pool dynamically creates accounts so it might be those that need access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now determined what was causing the above problem...

Our sites on IIS run in a number of shared application pools running as a domain user. We also have a Windows scheduler job which runs a number of scripts over night which also run as the same domain user.

It seems there are cases when this scheduler job runs it interferes with the IIS worker processes. When it completes and ends its user session it unloads the registry file in memory, which the w3wp.exe processes could also using.

This error is presented in the Event log...

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
>   applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The
>   applications or services that hold your registry file may not function
>   properly afterwards. No user action is required.

Along with references to the w3wp.exe processes currently running.

It was replicated when I terminal serviced in as the domain user and logged out again after a period of time. The event log presented the error and the sites all bombed shortly afterwards.

Running the scheduled job as a different user has fixed this issue for us.

Comment: Thanks! We had the same issue, but different cause. We had a windows service using the same user as the application pool. To recreate, we killed the service process (stopping the service was not enough).

Answer (score 0):

I remember having an include file for ADOVBS.inc with all the ADO constants inside and including it as a standard ASP include inside my global include file which is included on every page on the site.

This was before I used the META way of including the file.

So maybe a last resort is to revert to that method of loading in the ADO constants.

It seems like some sort of threshold is being hit, CPU/Memory?, which then prevents IIS caching/loading the file in from the registry. This then causes the error and a recycle of the pool. As no redirect is being done to the 500.100.asp error handler page which hides the error details from the user. It would suggest the error is in IIS and related to the server.

Thanks